# Sketch the graph of $g(x)= \displaystyle \frac {1}{2} f(x-4)$

Tags: calculus, functions

[image]

I am really sorry that I can not sketch the graph in latex. Sketch in the above is graph of $f(x)$. For graph I can definitely say that $f(2)=0$

**Question** is can you sketch the graph of $g(x)$ where $g(x)= \displaystyle \frac {1}{2} f(x-4)$

In my opinion, I can get so close the point for example $3$ and the image of $3$ under $f$ is approximately 4 so that would imply that $g(6)$ is so close to point $2$. I can continue this process until it is clear.

My second question: Is there any way to sketch this graph? OR my idea was just waste of time.

Comment: You can read off some points from the graph of $f$, then use them to determine points on the graph of $g$. But it's probably quicker to think in terms of the transformations from $f$ to $g$. What is the difference between the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x-4)$? What about $y= \frac{1}{2} f(x)$? The graph of $g$ is going to involve both of those in some way.

Answer (score 1):

One has that:

- $f(x-a)$ corresponds to a traslation of the graph by $+a$ in the $x$ direction
- $b\cdot f(x)$ ($b>0$)corresponds to a vertical dilation of the graph by a factor $b$.

Thus for $f(x+4)$ you have to translate the graph by $-4$ in the $x$ direction. Then for $\frac{1}{2}f(x+4)$ you *squeeze* the graph vertically toward the $x$ axis by halving the *oscillations/peaks*.